# error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Keycloak

Tags: java, jboss, keycloak

I have problem with deploying app with Keycloak:

> DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
>     Deployment "vfs:///D:/jboss-6.1.0.Final/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/keycloak-demo-ear.ear" is in error due to the \ following reason(s): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.component.UIComponent from BaseClassLoader@6929c1c6{vfs:///D:/jboss-6.1.0.Final/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/keycloak-demo-ear.ear}

or this one :

> DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:   Deployment
>   "vfs:///D:/jboss-6.1.0.Final/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/keycloak-demo.ear" is in error due to the following reason(s):
>   org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL
>   file:/D:/jboss-6.1.0.Final/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/keycloak-demo-ear.ear/keycloak-demo-web.war/ deployment failed

Error appears when below code is added to `web.xml`

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>KEYCLOAK</auth-method>
    <realm-name>demo</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

I have created `keycloak.json` in `WEB-INF` from admin console like:

```
{
  "realm": "demo",
  "realm-public-key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCrVrCuTtArbgaZzL1hvh0xtL5mc7o0NqPVnYXkLvgcwiC3BjLGw1tGEGoJaXDuSaRllobm53JBhjx33UNv+5z/UMG4kytBWxheNVKnL6GgqlNabMaFfPLPCF8kAgKnsi79NMo+n6KnSY8YeUmec/p2vjO2NjsSAVcWEQMVhJ31LwIDAQAB",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "panel",
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "6c3fa646-f033-4864-8b87-604887ce8eec"
  }
}
```

I added to `Keycloak` configuration from redme file to standalone/configuration/standalone.xml:

For WildFly and JBoss EAP 6.x

```
<extensions>
    <extension module="org.keycloak.keycloak-subsystem"/>
    ...
</extensions>

<profile>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.0">
        <auth-server name="main-auth-server">
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <web-context>auth</web-context>
        </auth-server>
    </subsystem>
    ...
</profile>
```

I am using this keycloak (keycloak-appliance-dist-all-1.1.0.Final) `http://sourceforge.net/projects/keycloak/files/1.1.0.Final/keycloak-appliance-dist-all-1.1.0.Final.zip/download`

I deployed succesfully examples keycloak 1.1.0 from package and want to use keycloak in my app. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I think I found element which causes problem:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>keycloak-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    <relativePath>../../../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

When I delete this `parent` from example project, it stops working

My app structure is

> mainapp
>   ...  pom.xml
>        ... module1
>        ...
>        pom.xml
>   ... module2
>        ...
>        pom.xml
>   ... module3 ... pom.xml

every module has `parent` to `mainapp`

when i add parent from `keycloak` to `mainapp` `pom.xml` i have error on `parent` to `mainapp` in `pom.xml` of other modules like:

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:

I also tried to add `dependency` to `keycloak-parent` but still id doesn't work

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keycloak consists of a server (Keycloak server) and an adapter that protects your application and handles authentication. If you are deploying your own application in the same server as the Keycloak server, you need to add the Keycloak adapter to the server as already mentioned (see [Keycloak adapters](https://docs.jboss.org/keycloak/docs/1.2.0.CR1/userguide/html/ch08.html)). Latest versions of Keycloak are shipped as a preconfigured Wildfly 9 so that might be appropriate for your application. There are also adapters for other containers or for pure HTML clients.

From your question I guess that you are trying to modify Keycloak examples into your own application. The Keycloak examples use a shared parent POM so it might want to strip that down to a single POM to get a better overview. Or, depending on your expertise, you could start with a basic JEE application with JAAS security and deploy that into the Keycloak server (with the JBoss/Wildfly adapter installed). See e.g. [Oracle's JEE 6 Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijrp.html).

Answer (score 0):

In order to have your app working with keycloak you must install an adapter on your server. Here are the details:
https://docs.jboss.org/keycloak/docs/1.1.0.Final/userguide/html/ch08.html

You can deploy a keycloak subsystem or a keycloak.json file at your WEB-INF/. Both cases you have to install the adapter
Regards

Comment: link is broken now see https://keycloak.github.io/docs/userguide/keycloak-server/html/ch08.html instead